# How to search all nested resources without the parent resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

My app's got **Listings** nested within **Categories**.

I can search all the listings when I'm in a particular category with this form:

```
<%= form_tag category_listings_path(@category), method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I must make a get request to the `category_listings_path` and pass in the current `Category`.

However, this method fails when I want to put the search bar on a page where no `Category` exists!

How can I search for all `Listing`s without needing to pass in a `Category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I'm guessing your routes look something like:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :listings
end
```

This means that all of your routes for listings require a category id. If you want a path for all listings, regardless of category, add:

```
resources :listings, only: [:index]
```

to your routes. Then you can have a form that searches to `listings_path` (which is the path that above route creates) and you don't need a category id.